# Pentaho Kettle - How to produce update query based on result set?

Tags: mysql, pentaho, jobs, kettle, data-integration

I come up with [Insert query generator](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/SQL+File+Output) from pentaho spoon that writes input data to a text file in the form of a set of SQL statements.

I wonder if there is any method that can be used similar to this but generate update query based on input.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you need to update a table based on some key columns compared to your stream, you may use the [Insert/Update](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Insert+-+Update) step.

The downside is that it won't generate the statements in a file, it will execute the updates or inserts based on that comparison and that's all.

Can you give more details about your scenario? We may work things out together.
Why do you need a file with UPDATE statements? 
Can't we connect to the database and run the updates right away?

Comment: thanks for your response, Insert/Update step directly insert data into table. I need a sql statement for update. Things is that there are lot of databases and need update query so that it can be easily run on server without using other databases on the server side.

Comment: Have you tried the 'Merge rows (diff)' step? It marks the rows that need to be updates. I'm pretty sure that you may use that to filter the rows to be updated and use a formula field to generate the statement with all columns.

Answer (score 0):

Sure use the "Dynamic SQL Row" step.